# Adding a line to the beginning of a BAT text file

Tags: command-line, batch-file, cmd.exe

There is a code that adds the line `"WORD, 1234, A, B, C"` to the beginning of a text file.

After executing the code, an extra character `""` is added at the end of the text file.

Please help me fix the code so that there is now this character `""` at the end of the text file.

```
set line=!line::=:00!
    
@echo off

pushd C:\123\123
    
for %%a in (file.txt) do (
     >>$ echo WORD,1234,A,B,C
     >nul (copy $+"%%a"& move $ "%%a")
   )
 
set xname=%xname:s=s%
  
exit /b
```

In Notepad++ you see: [image]

Comment: Can you explain a little better i don't understand what you want.

Comment: @RicardoBohner with this OP code one non printable character is added to the file.txt

Comment: Thank you my friend @It wasn't me

Comment: @RicardoBohner I hope that you have understood my //English :)

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off 

>"%temp%\tmp_file.txt" (
    echo\WORD,1234,A,B,C
    type "C:\123\123\file.txt"|find/v "%:^)"
) && move /y "%temp%\tmp_file.txt" "C:\123\123\file.txt"
```

**1.** Echo your string and redirect (`>`) to a temporary file with a unique name:

```
echo\WORD,1234,A,B,C>"%temp%\tmp_file.txt"
```

**2.** Use `type file.txt|find "not existing string"` to list all lines in your file (including blank ones)

```
type "C:\123\123\file.txt"|find/v "_string_not_exist_in_file"
```

**3.** Use your commands in block `()` where your merge files outputs following by operator `&&`, if all your commands `return 0` (execution successfully), you can move your new file to the target file (overwriting `/y` old contend of `file.txt`):

```
(...commands..) && move /y "%temp%\tmp_file.txt" "C:\123\123\file.txt"
```

---

**Obs.: 1** This question use one generic string, for real one, you may check if anyone will need escaping:

- ```
     WORD,1234,A,B,C  
     special characters: ^| ^& ^> ^< ^^ %% ^{ ^}
  ```

**Obs.: 2** My English is terrible, sorry! And maybe I did not understand the application of these lines, some revision may be necessary, use the comments...

- ```
    set line=!line::=:00!   ==> variable line is not defined
    set xname=%xname:s=s%   ==> variable xname is not defined
    pushd C:\123\123        ==> replace to cd /d "C:\123\123"  // use "" ==> "path"
  ```

**Obs.: 3.** Specifically about `pushd C:\123\123`, as the path is known, you can use it directly in your commands, or replace it with `cd /d "drive:your_path_folder"`:

- ```
   ::   replace: pushd C:\123\123  
  ::        to: cd /d "C:\123\123"
     
  @echo off 
     
  cd /d "C:\123\123"
    
  >"%temp%\tmp_file.txt" (
    echo\WORD,1234,A,B,C
    type "\file.txt"|find/v "%:^)"
  ) && move /y "%temp%\tmp_file.txt" "file.txt"
  ```

---

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[Move /?](https://ss64.com/nt/move.html)**

  [√] **[Find /?](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)**

  [√] **[Findstr /?](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)**

  [√] **[Redirection |, <, > 2>, ...](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)**

  [√] **[Conditional Execution || && ...](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**

  [√] **[Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes in Command Line](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)**

**[How does the Windows Command Interpreter cmd.exe Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts)**

**[How-to: Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes at the Windows command line](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)**